# Devexpress Lookup editor function as a regular ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress, lookup

I need Devexpress Lookup editor function as a regular ComboBox, so after user click cell in grid, another grid with multiple columns appears. User can also add new value but new value can't save in data source, but after enter form the next time the value won't disappear. Right now I have simple RepositoryItemTextEdit in cell and there are already values, so after changes in code the values must stay the same.

Right now the values outside from data source disappears after leaving and entering form. The values from data source stays, but after cell looses focus the value in cell says "Value is empty".

My code so far (I used https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E2297):

```
//////////////////////class MyObject
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections;

namespace APP
{
    public class MyObject
    {
        public MyObject()
        {}

        private object _Value;
        public object Value
        {
            get { return _Value; }
            set { _Value = value; }
        }
    }
}

//////////////class MyDataSourceWrapper
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections;

namespace APP
{
    class MyDataSourceWrapper : ITypedList, IList
    {
        private readonly string _DisplayMember;
        public readonly IList NestedList;
        public ITypedList NestedTypedList { get { return (ITypedList)NestedList; } }
        public MyDataSourceWrapper(ITypedList list, MyObject nullObject, string valueMember, string displayMember)
        {
            _ValueMember = valueMember;
            _DisplayMember = displayMember;
            _NullObject = nullObject;
            this.NestedList = (IList)list;
        }

        private MyObject _NullObject;
        private readonly string _ValueMember;
        public MyObject NullObject
        {
            get { return _NullObject; }
            set { _NullObject = value; }
        }

        class EmptyObjectPropertyDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
        {
            private readonly string _DisplayMember;
            public readonly PropertyDescriptor NestedDescriptor;
            public readonly MyObject NullObject;
            private readonly string _ValueMember;
            public EmptyObjectPropertyDescriptor
                (PropertyDescriptor nestedDescriptor, MyObject nullObject, string valueMember, string displayMember)
                : base(nestedDescriptor.Name, (Attribute[])new ArrayList(nestedDescriptor.Attributes).ToArray(typeof(Attribute)))
            {
                _DisplayMember = displayMember;
                _ValueMember = valueMember;
                this.NestedDescriptor = nestedDescriptor;
                this.NullObject = nullObject;
            }
            public override bool CanResetValue(object component)
            {
                return false;
            }
            public override Type ComponentType
            {
                get { return typeof(object); }
            }
            public override object GetValue(object component)
            {
                if (component == NullObject)
                {
                    if (NestedDescriptor.Name == _ValueMember)
                        return NullObject.Value;
                    else if (NestedDescriptor.Name == _DisplayMember)
                        return NullObject.Value;
                    return null;
                }
                else
                    return NestedDescriptor.GetValue(component);
            }
            public override bool IsReadOnly
            {
                get { return true; }
            }
            public override Type PropertyType
            {
                get { return NestedDescriptor.PropertyType; }
            }
            public override void ResetValue(object component)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("The method or operation is not implemented.");
            }
            public override void SetValue(object component, object value)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("The method or operation is not implemented.");
            }
            public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetItemProperties(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
        {
            List<PropertyDescriptor> result = new List<PropertyDescriptor>();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor pd in NestedTypedList.GetItemProperties(ExtractOriginalDescriptors(listAccessors)))
            {
                object nullVal = null;
                if (pd.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                    nullVal = "[empty]";
                result.Add(new EmptyObjectPropertyDescriptor(pd, NullObject, _ValueMember, _DisplayMember));
            }
            return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(result.ToArray());
        }
        public string GetListName(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
        {
            return NestedTypedList.GetListName(ExtractOriginalDescriptors(listAccessors));
        }

        protected static PropertyDescriptor[] ExtractOriginalDescriptors(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
        {
            if (listAccessors == null)
                return null;
            PropertyDescriptor[] convertedDescriptors = new PropertyDescriptor[listAccessors.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < convertedDescriptors.Length; ++i)
            {
                PropertyDescriptor d = listAccessors[i];
                EmptyObjectPropertyDescriptor c = d as EmptyObjectPropertyDescriptor;
                if (c != null)
                    convertedDescriptors[i] = c.NestedDescriptor;
                else
                    convertedDescriptors[i] = d;
            }
            return convertedDescriptors;
        }
        public int Add(object value)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("The method or operation is not implemented.");
        }
        public void Clear()
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("The method or operation is not implemented.");
        }
        public bool Contains(object value)
        {
            if (value == NullObject)
                return true;
            return NestedList.Contains(value);
        }
        public int IndexOf(object value)
        {
            if (value == NullObject)
                return 0;
            int nres = NestedList.IndexOf(value);
            if (nres < 0)
                return nres;
            return nres + 1;
        }
        public void Insert(int index, object value)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("The method or operation is not implemented.");
        }
        public bool IsFixedSize
        {
            get { return true; }
        }
        public bool IsReadOnly
        {
            get { return true; }
        }
        public void Remove(object value)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("The method or operation is not implemented.");
        }
        public void RemoveAt(int index)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("The method or operation is not implemented.");
        }
        public object this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                if (index == 0)
                    return NullObject;
                else
                    return NestedList[index - 1];
            }
            set
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("The method or operation is not implemented.");
            }
        }
        public void CopyTo(Array array, int index)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("The method or operation is not implemented.");
        }
        public int Count
        {
            get { return NestedList.Count + 1; }
        }
        public bool IsSynchronized
        {
            get { return false; }
        }
        public object SyncRoot
        {
            get { return NestedList.SyncRoot; }
        }
        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("The method or operation is not implemented.");
        }
    }
}

//////////////////class MyGridLookupDataSourceHelper
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DevExpress.XtraEditors;
using DevExpress.XtraGrid;
using System.Collections;

using DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository;
using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns;
using DevExpress.XtraLayout;
using DevExpress.Utils;

namespace APP
{
    public class MyGridLookupDataSourceHelper
    {

        MyObject _MyObject = new MyObject();
        private MyDataSourceWrapper _DataSourceWrapper;
        GridLookUpEdit edit;
        bool popupOpened = false;
        public MyGridLookupDataSourceHelper(GridLookUpEdit edit, ITypedList dataSource, string displayMember, string valueMember)
        {
            this.edit = edit;
            _DataSourceWrapper = new MyDataSourceWrapper(dataSource, _MyObject, valueMember, displayMember);
            edit.Properties.DisplayMember = displayMember;
            edit.Properties.ValueMember = valueMember;
            edit.Properties.DataSource = _DataSourceWrapper;
            edit.Properties.View.CustomRowFilter += View_CustomRowFilter;
            edit.ProcessNewValue += edit_ProcessNewValue;
            edit.Properties.View.RefreshData();
            edit.Properties.QueryPopUp += new CancelEventHandler(Properties_QueryPopUp);
        }

        void Properties_QueryPopUp(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            this.popupOpened = true;
            edit.Properties.View.DataController.DoRefresh();
        }

        public static void SetupGridLookUpEdit(GridLookUpEdit edit, ITypedList dataSource, string displayMember, string valueMember)
        {
            new MyGridLookupDataSourceHelper(edit, dataSource, displayMember, valueMember);
        }

        void View_CustomRowFilter(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.RowFilterEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!popupOpened) return;
            if (_DataSourceWrapper[e.ListSourceRow] is MyObject)
            {
                e.Visible = false;
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        void edit_ProcessNewValue(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ProcessNewValueEventArgs e)
        {
            _MyObject.Value = e.DisplayValue;
            this.popupOpened = false;
            edit.Properties.View.DataController.DoRefresh();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}

/////////////////////////code used in Main
   GridLookUpEdit glue = new GridLookUpEdit();
            glue.Properties.TextEditStyle = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.TextEditStyles.Standard;
            MyGridLookupDataSourceHelper.SetupGridLookUpEdit(glue, GetMaterialyDataView(), "Kod", "Kod");
            eePozycje.gvView.Columns[KolNazwa].ColumnEdit = glue.Properties;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have modified the example a little bit and your written code will not work as you expect. If you want to use grid lookup edit grid column then you must use repository item. You should use `RepositoryItemGridLookUpEdit` rather than `GridLookUpEdit`.

After that you will be able to view separate gridview under that column editor(RepositoryItemGridLookUpEdit), then you can see another gridview in a Grid column under grid lookup editor.

Hope this help.